# Is it possible to reach an SES EndPoint from a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-ses

I'm have a sample test lambda function that send email through SES.
Without a VPC the Lambda function works.

I created a VPN and a security group with inbound rules similar to I found in a aws post for EC2 [Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) for VPC Endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/aws/new-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-for-vpc-endpoints/),
except for "source" that I set to "0.0.0.0/0"

[image: inbound settings]

When I test the function it gives a time out

[image]

Is it possible to reach an SES EndPoint from a lambda function?
What I'missing?

Comment: Have you checked your IAM as it may go internally instead of querying out depending on your code - take a look here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/

Comment: The Execution role have have mucth more that "ses:SendEmail",             "ses:SendRawEmail": it has also "lambda:InvokeFunction","ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
"ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",  "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",               "ec2:DescribeInstances", "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface", "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute", "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*".   Anyway, if it was an authorization issue, shouldn't I get an error instead of a timeout?

Comment: Not all the time, time-out can be causes silently from the smtp service on SES. Can also happen if your sandboxed by AWS